# Replace 1d list as a column of a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
pt_list = [3, 4, 32, 20, 20, 10, 10, 13, 30, 10]

pt = 0

points = [
    ['1.', pt],
    ['2.', pt],
    ['3.', pt],
    ['4.', pt],
    ['5.', pt],
    ['6.', pt],
    ['7.', pt],
    ['8.', pt],
    ['9.', pt],
    ['10.', pt]
]

for i in range(0,10,1):
    for j in points:
        points[i][1] = j
```

I tried some different ways and I can't find anything on the internet for this specific example. I would like to have the `pt_list` inside of each `pt`, so the first one would be `['1.', 3]` the second one `['2.', 4]` and the third one `['3.'32']` and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One loop will work: `for i in range(10): points[i][1] = pt_list[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which allows you to iterate the two lists in tandem, taking the 0-th column from each row of the 2d list `points`:

```py
points = [[x[0], y] for x, y in zip(points, pt_list)]
```

The nested loop you've attempted won't be effective for this sort of problem (that approach would give you a Cartesian Product of the two lists -- for each element of list 1, pair it with each element from list 2), but you can fix your code as follows:

```
for i in range(len(points)):
    points[i][1] = pt_list[i]
```

Note that I've used `len(points)` rather than the hardcoded 10.

These solutions assume your lists are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax to initialize this particular 2D list:

```
ls = [[str(i+1)+'.',pt_list[i]] for i in range(0,10)]
```

This is known as list comprehension, and it basically means that we are generating i lists where i is in range from 0 to 10, and that each element would be:

```
[str(i+1)+'.',pt_list[i]]
```

You can also understand this by manuallly substituting values of i from 0..10 and see what values it gives.

You can also change the value 10 with len(pt_list)..